# Formatting a paragraph to conform to 80% of the browser size not 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating pages for a site, and I've been having to use `<br>` scripts to conform the text to make it readily readable on smaller devices as well as larger.

Is there a way to constrain the text to a percentage of the page without altering the other content? (at 80% of the browser window) much like an image can be constrained to the size of the browser page. Would I need to create an actual text document and insert it as an image?

I've tried using "textarea", "body", "hgroups", and "p" to no avail. I'm referring to using something like:

```
<img src="example.jpg" width="50%" alt=""/>
```

but with a text area, box, etc. and allowing it to expand vertically as an inverse proportion to the width. I'm not really picky so long as it doesn't need a scroll bar and can display the entire paragraph. I'm not looking to change the size of the text itself.

In a sense that makes the width and height inverse properties so that all the text will be viewable. It should still conform to the browser window at a certain percentage of the window rather than the default 100%. I've also tried using borders, margins, and padding. I have the feeling I'm just missing a key component.

Comment: Whenever you ask a question on stack overflow you need to put code or we can't even register anything.

Comment: I'm a noob to coding I apologize, only been at this a few days

Comment: Check out the `<div>` tag: [http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_div_tag.htm]()

Comment: Please use a website like JSFiddle or the built-in Stack Snippets feature (edit your post and it'll be an option in the WYSIWYG editor) to include a reproducible example of the code that you have at this time. Also, it sounds like you just need to apply `width: 80%;` to the element that contains your text. Just remember to set a specific width to the parent element as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way I can think of:

```
p.full-width {
    width:80%;
    padding: 0 20% 0 20%;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: I'll use that next time I start a new page, I'm still new to this, and I was trying to figure out if there was an easy way to format the text area width on this particular page by a % conformity rather than pixel width, as there are lots of images and other content that would be resized by your coding as well. I'll definitely use that next time I start a page though, thank you!

Comment: The above code only target paragraph <p> elements with the class of "full-width". So, <p class="full-width"></p>.

Comment: Additionally, if you needed this to work for an actual <textarea>, simply change out the p to textarea.

Comment: aha! Sorry, I'm still learning. Only been at this a week.

Comment: Just put it in use, works exactly how i needed it to! thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. If my response fixed your issue, please set my answer as the correct one by clicking the Checkmark to the left of my initial post. Thank you, and good luck in your coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
#some_div{
  width:80%;
  margin-left:none;
 }
```

Add width as 80% and take out left margin and also padding if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood you quite well. Is it making a text be like a background image? To be behind of all the content and adjust according to the window size?

If so, maybe this?

```
div.text-bg-container {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%
  height:100%;
  font-size:80%
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: it's to make the text width conform to 80% of the browser window width while making the height automatically realign so that there is no need for a scroll bar on the side.

Answer (score 0):

HTML: structure (which boxes are within other boxes)

CSS: styling (setting widths, borders, animations)

JS: interaction (add click listeners, send JSONs over http://, etc)

---

### Target your HTML `<div>` tag or whatever with DOM selectors:

### CSS:

`.someDivClass {
    width: 80%
}`

`#someDivID {
    left: 0%,
    right: 20%
}`

---

### JS:

`var element = document.querySelector(".someDivClass")`

or

`var element = document.querySelector("#myID")`

then

`element.setAttribute("style", "width:80%");`

or

`element.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    alert('hello')
});`

for example

---

Only one element can have a unique ID `id="myDivID"`, where as many elements can have the same `class="myDivClass"` defined in their `<div>` tag (div is the most basic DOM element, and most every DOM element is a div with additional, baked in functionality by default)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set the size of an element relative to browser window, you can use [Viewport-percentage lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths). Something like:

```
p {
    font-size: 10vw;
}
```

Here is a simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymk0o8ar/) example. Resize your browser window to see the difference.